Discrete nonabelian free subgroups of semisimple Lie groups
I understand that the following is a theorem: If $G$ is a noncompact connected semisimple Lie group, then $G$ contains a discrete nonabelian free subgroup.
I can find proofs that such a $G$ contains a nonabelian free subgroup, but whether the resulting subgroups are discrete is unclear (there seems to be much focus on dense free subgroups). Assuming the result stated above is correct, could someone point me to a reference and proof?

All such groups $G$ contain a closed subgroup locally isomorphic to $SL(2,\mathbb R)$. Now, if you know anything about free groups, you would know how to find a discrete free subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb R)$...

I know how to find discrete free subgroups of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, but I'm not used to thinking about local isomorphisms, so I'd have to convince myself that this would carry through to $G$. But as a followup, what's a reference for this fact about closed subgroups locally isomorphic to $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$?

Pretty much any textbook on Lie groups or Lie algebras will give you this result, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson%E2%80%93Morozov_theorem#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Jacobson%E2%80%93Morozov,after%20Jacobson%201951%2C%20Morozov%201942.

Also if you think about the Iwasawa decomposition and the root system of your Lie algebra...
